# How would you save form info when reloading a web page?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, passwords

So I have a small database for me and my friends to use, and I wish to have it password protected by a webpage before it called, "DBAccess.php" but when you enter the actual "DB.php" webpage and reload the page for a POST, it will then remove the variable data that saved the inserted data(the passcode). Is there any way to save specific variables on a reload specifically, if not forever until a log out button is pressed?

P.S. I tried to use $_SESSION but cannot wrap my head around it, little less make it do what I need it to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$_SESSION` to do this. Is not a good idea POST every request in body you passcode. Session is easy to use, you need to start in EVERY page of php where you need session variable, with `session_start()`. After starting the session you can read, insert, edit, delete a session variable.

**Set variable**:
`$_SESSION['passcode'] = $_POST['session'];`

**Read variable**:
`echo $_SESSION['passcode'];`

You can protect your area with a check if is set this session variable `$_SESSION['passcode']`